# Force Nginx to create a new process for each request

Tags: nginx, configuration, process

Nginx reverse proxy send and receives requests from client to a defined port, that usually is a process that responds to requests the thing is if for one of requests the process crashes the whole parallel threads also crash, I know it should be avoided and by using services it can run after the crash, but can nginx utilizes multiple separate parallel processes? it also has a drawback of loosing statics but in my case it is not important.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:8000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using HAProxy it is a load balancer and does the job:

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
    #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256::RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend Local_Server
    bind 192.168.1.12:80
    mode http
    default_backend My_Web_Servers

backend My_Web_Servers
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1rnHost:localhost
    server web1.example.com  192.168.1.101:80
    server web2.example.com  192.168.1.102:80
    server web3.example.com  192.168.1.103:80

listen stats *:1936
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats refresh 30s
    stats show-node
    stats auth username:password
    stats uri  /stats
```